# I am using a widget with interact to plot points on a graph as they are selected, but I have problems when trying to use a button to control plt.plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipywidgets

The code that works is as follows:

```
def f(x,y):              
    display(x,y)
    plt.plot(x,y,'bo')   
    return (x,y)

widgets.interact(f,x=[('1',10),('2',20),('3',30),('4',40)],
                   y=[('1',1),('2',2),('3',3),('4',4)])
```

But the problem is that the point is plotted whenever x or y changes. I inserted a button widget to have the program wait until both x and y are selected before calling the plt.plot() function as shown below, but when Enter is pressed, I get an error message saying that y is not defined. The modified code that doesn't work is shown below.

```
def f(x,y):              
    display(x,y)
    return (x,y)

def plot_point(x,y):
    plt.plot(x,y,'bo')
    return 

widgets.interact(f,x=[('1',10),('2',20),('3',30),('4',40)],
                   y=[('1',1),('2',2),('3',3),('4',4)])

   
btn=widgets.Button(description='Enter')
display(btn)
btn.on_click(plot_point)
```

Comment: Hello there! Please share the full error output of your code as well as things you've already tried.

Comment: The error says, 'plot_point() missing one required positional argument: 'y'.

Comment: I have tried separating the widget statement into two:  one for x and one for y and having a def f(x) and def (y). I have also tried putting the function for plot_point inside the def f(x,y) block since def f(x,y) seems to work fine. I also tried using 'x' for x and 'y' for y in the plot_point() function and on another occasion, in the plt.plot() statement.  I really can't think of anything else to do.

Comment: I have also tried: ```def plot_point(x.value,y.value):``` and ```plt.plot(x.value,y.value,'bo')``` but those gave the error of x not being defined.